# Access to attributes of filtered objects in Django Templates

Tags: django

I want to show list of galleries (name of gallery and first image) like this:

```
         {% for gallery in galleries %}
            <a href="/gallery/{{ gallery.slug }}">
              <div class="gallery_box">
                 <h2>{{ gallery.translatedName }}</h2>
                 <img src="{{ (gallery.image_set.all|first).path }}"/>
              </div>
            </a>                         
        {% endfor %}
```

but

```
 {{ (gallery.image_set.all|first).path }}
```

is invalid.
How Can I get access to attribute 'path' for

```
 {{ gallery.image_set.all|first }}
```

Comment: see answer below, also 
    {{gallery.image_set.all.0.image.url}}

depends on how your model field is named, it this case it would be "image".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of using the `first` filter you can just do `{{ gallery.image_set.all.0.path }}`

Answer (score 5):

JamesO has the right answer but if you really need to use a filter, you can use `with`:

```
{% with gallery.image_set.all|first as first_image %}{{ first_image.path }}{% endwith %}
```